# Associate .less files with notepad ++

Tags: notepad++, file-association, css, less

I just love notepad++ however I'm working with .less files and when I open  a .less file it's just a normal text not  a language (css) no code highlighting  is there a plugin or something to make notepad++ recognize the .less files?
I could go to language and choose CSS, But isn't there a smarter way?

Comment: You can add LESS as User Defined Language

http://stackoverflow.com/a/10161795/1242333

Answer (score 2):

Just go into the *Style Configurator*, choose CSS from the list and add the extension to *User ext*.